# Force focus (and restore if minimized) iOS App on macOS

Tags: ios, macos, window, focus, mac-catalyst

So far I have successfully adapted my app to run on macOS. But there is one thing missing, I want to force-focus my application when a certain notification is triggered.

I have tried using the UiWindow property `windowLevel` and the method `makeKeyAndVisible` but they didn‘t do anything.
Does somebody know what else I could try to get my app focused and restored (if it got minimized) ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `UIWindow.makeKeyAndVisible` is ignored in catalyst, but activating the `UISceneSession` that contains the window does what you're after.

```swift
if let session = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.first {
    UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(session, userActivity: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)
}
```

Note that calling `requestSceneSessionActivation` with `nil` as the first argument will just open a new window.